# How to fix problem with downloading file with &quot; in name

Tags: java, fileutils

I have a problem with the opening stream to a remote file `http://localhost:8081/generatedfiles/ready/imagesTo&quot;Trans.zip`.

But I get `FileNotFoundException`. When I remove `&quot;` entity from URL and existing file, everything works fine.

**I've tried** changing request URL to `http://localhost:8081/generatedfiles/ready/imagesTo%26quot%3BTrans.zip`, but still throws an exception.

**Code snippet:**

```
URL externalFileURL = new URI(externalFilePath).toURL();
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(externalFileURL, localFile);
```

**I expect** to download file under given URL with `&quot;` in its name. Currently, it's not possible. I know that it's strange to have quote in the file name (it's forbidden on windows), but I have to handle such a scenario.

Comment: Dont construct the url by hand

Comment: Do you mean multi-argument constructor of URI class?

Comment: You cannot use HTML entities in filenames, you must URL encode the filename.

Comment: I still have a problem with copying file with semicolon in its name. Sample URL: http://localhost:8081/generatedfiles/%3B.docx.zip. It works fine on Windows, but on linux it throws FileNotFoundException. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Open a new question.  This might be an encoding problem on the server side.